# Must String.format() declare culture invariance?

Tags: .net, casting, cultureinfo

Recently new job and got a question regarding an error in the software from a customer. The error is "Conversion from string '0.5' to type 'double' is not valid."

I believe I have found the offending line. Because the customer is in France and has his computers settings all in french (numbering system, language,...) that the "0.5" can't be casted to french number version of "0,5" The French system has no decimals anywhere in their numbers. So, if string.format sees "0.5" it won't know what to do, because there is no '.' character to be casted to double in french culture settings. Am I right here?

```
context.Append(String.Format("{0} {1} exceeds fine {2} limit of {3:N0}", _
       context.OccupancyState, context.Size, _
       Reg.Alert.ToLower, context.Limit))
```

Where context.Size holds the "0.5" string.

Does format.string take into account the culture settings, or am I missing something here?

EDIT:

Just tried it on french windows VM, and (unfortunately) it was able to parse it as "0,5" successfully...So maybe that isn't the problem?

Comment: `String.Format` doesn't _parse_. It formats a string according to the types you are using. If you pass a string, it will not be formatted at all. So either  this is not correct: _"...where context.Size holds the "0.5" string"_ or this: _"it was able to parse it as "0,5" successfully"_.

Comment: How did the string "0.5" end up in a French computer?  Why is a size stored as a string instead of a number?  That statement doesn't otherwise convert context.Size from a string to a double so you haven't found the problem yet.

Comment: Sorry for the details Hans, I am still new getting into this software, and it seems to do many strange things :(

Comment: Thank you Tim, your knowledge helped tremendously. I went behind that call to find the part that ACTUALLY parsed it and found the error and have fixed it accordingly by making the underlying structure culture invariant, but the display in french (or any current culture) notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the string to a double first, otherwise `String.Format` will just concat the string  without any formatting.

```
double d = double.Parse(context.Size, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string formatted = String.Format("{0} {1} exceeds fine {2} limit of {3:N0}"
                                 , context.OccupancyState, context.Size
                                 , Reg.Alert.ToLower, context.Limit);
```

Now `string.Format` will use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` when it formats the double to a string again.

Answer (score 2):

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
context.Append(String.Format(culture, "{0} {1} exceeds fine {2} limit of {3:N0}", _
       context.OccupancyState, context.Size, _
       Reg.Alert.ToLower, context.Limit))
```

Answer (score 1):

String formatting and parsing does take the computer's culture/locale into account, so if you know that all your numbers are going to output with a decimal point and entered in the same format then you will have to pass an invariant culture to the formatting and parsing methods.

Though you say `context.Size` holds the **string** "0.5". This doesn't make sense as it's the second argument and so will replace the `{1}` in the string.Format.

What is probably going wrong is that the code is attempting to `context.Limit` to a decimal to output with the `{3:N0}` formatting. If *this* string is "0.5" then that would cause the error on French machines (or any PC with a decimal comma) as that's not a valid numeric with that format.

So either store your numbers as numbers or don't try and format your already formatted strings as numbers.